# Java Comparator to sort the student ids of college student from lowest number to highest

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Here is my code and please don't give me the solution to the assignment. Can anyone enlighten me on the compile error? And why exactly it is not working. I wrote a code like this before...

Simple code:

Student.java

```
public class Student 
{
    private int id;

    public Student(int NewId)
    {
        id = NewId;
    }
    public int getId(){ return id; }
    public void setId(int NewId){ id = NewId; }
}
```

Sort.java

```
public class Sort
{
    public static Comparator<Student> getStudentIdComparator()
    {
        return new IdComparator();//<- compile error
    }

    class IdComparator implements Comparator<Student>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) 
        {
            return o1.getId() - o2.getId();
        }
    }
}
```

MainFile.java

```
class MainFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student s[] = new Student[10];
        // Here you would just create the instance variable with student id in                 the argument 
        Comparator<Student> studentIdComparator = Sort.getStudentIdComparator();

        Arrays.sort(students, studentIdComparator);
     }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 No enclosing instance of type Sorter is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Sorter (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Sorter).

 at Sorter.getStudentIdComparator(Sorter.java:17)
 at Tester.main(Tester.java:21)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access non static class from within static class.

Just add static keyword before your comparator class definition like:

```
static class IdComparator implements Comparator<Student>
```

or using instance of Sort like:

```
new Sort().new IdComparator();
```

Also avoid using `return o1.getId() - o2.getId();` as it may lead to underflow. Use

```
return Integer.compare(o1.getId(), o2.getId());
```

Comment: What exactly is static and what does it do within this context?

Comment: Plus one for the advice about underflow.  (It can't happen if the IDs are never negative, but your suggestion is good practice nontheless.)

Answer (score 0):

You've made `IdComparator` an *inner class*.

```
public class Sort{

    class IdComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Since you didn't put `static` on `IdComparator`, it means that every instance of `IdComparator` *belongs* to some instance of `Sort`.  An `IdComparator` instance will have a hidden reference that refers to the `Sort` object that contains it.  Because of this, you can only use `new IdComparator` in ways that specify a `Sort` object to contain it.  If `x` is a `Sort`, you can say

```
x.new IdComparator()
```

Or if you're in a **non-static** method of `Sort`, and you say

```
new IdComparator()
```

since the method is non-static, it will be operating on a specific `Sort` object, and the `new` uses that same object as the one that contains the new `IdComparator`.

But since you called it in a **static** method, there is no `Sort` object to contain it.  That's why you got an error.

You probably don't want the `IdComparator` objects to belong to specific `Sort` objects, because there aren't any `Sort` instance fields you need to refer to.  Adding `static` to the declaration of `IdComparator` makes it a *nested* class instead of an *inner* class.

```
public class Sort{

    static class IdComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you IdComparator class is a dynamic inner class like a normal field of you instance,but you main method is static,you can not use the static method to invoke the inner class instance directly.